# WSUS 3.0 updates not populating

Tags: windows, wsus, update

I set up a new Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with the intention of downloading and exporting WSUS data and metadata. I did an initial pull of updates for core operating systems like Win7, WinXP, etc. This initial pull brought in about 3800 updates or so. I approved them and they downloaded.

With the initial pull done I went back to content and added Office, SQL, Developer Tools, etc updates to be downloaded. I applied the new content I want updates for, but WSUS does not show me the new updates for approval. I refreshed WSUS and even restarted the machine, but WSUS still only shows me 3800 updates that have been already approved and downloaded.

Any ideas why WSUS is not pulling in the new updates I need so I can approve and download them?

Comment: I assume you have automatic synchronization on, and/or you synchronized manually, and that you selected both products and classifications.  Yes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I do have automatic sync enabled. I have selected both products and classifications. I will double check Automatic Sync when I am back with the system tomorrow.

Comment: Some folks have seen oddities in WSUS behavior when using a proxy or even firewall to connect to Microsoft.

Other folks have seen download problems with permissions issues on the location where files are being downloaded, or with quota/space issues.

In all cases they found useful information in their Application Event Logs - do you see any WSUS errors there on your machine?